# Selecting a subset of IDs

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `dt` with ids on the column `idnum` and a data.table `ids` that contains a list of ids in the column `idnum` (all of which exist on `dt`)

I want to get

- The intersection: `dt` where `dt.idnum ==`ids.idnum`
- The complement to the intersection: `dt` where `dt.idnum not in ids.idnum`

I got the first one with ease using

```
setkey(dt, idnum)
setkey(ids, idnum)
dt[ids]
```

However, Im stuck getting the second one. My approach was

```
dt[is.element(idnum, ids[, idnum]) == FALSE]
```

However, the row numbers of the two groups do not add up to `nrow(dt)`. I suspect the second command. What can I do instead / Where am I going wrong? Is there perhaps a more efficient way of computing the second group given that it's the complement to the first group and I already have that one?

**Update** 
I tried the approach given in the answer, but my numbers don't add up:

```
> nrow(x[J(ids$idnum)])
[1] 148
> nrow(x[!J(ids$idnum)])
[1] 52730
> nrow(x)
[1] 52863
```

While, the first two numbers added yield *52878*. That is, I have *15* rows too many. My data contains duplicates in *adj*, could that be the reason?

Here's some description of the data I used:

```
> str(x)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  52863 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ idnum: int  6 6 11 21 22 22 22 22 27 27 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "idnum"
> head(x)
   idnum
1:     6
2:     6
3:    11
4:    21
5:    22
6:    22


> str(ids)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  46 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ idnum: int  2909 5012 5031 5033 5478 6289 6405 6519 7923 7940 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "idnum"
> head(ids)
   idnum
1:  2909
2:  5012
3:  5031
4:  5033
5:  5478
6:  6289
```

and here is

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/C/C/C/C/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] yaml_2.1.13      ggplot2_1.0.0    mFilter_0.1-3   
[4] data.table_1.9.4 foreign_0.8-61  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-35      Rcpp_0.11.3      chron_2.3-45    
 [4] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1      
 [7] gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.3     munsell_0.4.2   
[10] plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     reshape2_1.4    
[13] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: *intersection* in "set" terms usually removes any duplicates. Ex: `intersect(c(1,1,2), c(1))`. Do you mean it this way? Or just matching rows in `dt` from `idnum` column.

Comment: It's hard to debug the issue you've in your data by working on some other data.. It'd really help with a minimal example where jlhoward's code doesn't provide the result you expect.

Comment: I mean matching rows. First I want all that are *in* the list `ids`, then I want all that are not. These two should be complements.

Comment: Regarding the data, I tried to randomly select from my data and I couldn't get the effect. I don't know which rows to include... If there's a way to post the whole column of 50k obs, that would be useful.

Comment: Maybe try [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)..? Also your `sessionInfo()` would be helpful.

Comment: I added `sessionInfo()` to the question. Here's the data: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9304616/

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look in a while (if no one else gets to it before).

Comment: I couldn't download it, as your link requires me to register/login. But your problem seems to be due to duplicate values, as spotted by @jlhoward. And his solution is right on as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)  # for reproducible example
dt <- data.table(idnum=1:1e5,x=rnorm(1e5))   # 10,000 rows, unique ids
ids <- data.table(idnum=sample(1:1e5,10))    # 10 random ids

setkey(dt,idnum)
result.1 <- dt[J(ids$idnum)]             # inclusive set (records with common ids)
result.2 <- dt[!J(ids$idnum)]            # exclusive set (records from dt with ids$idnum excluded
any(result.2$idnum %in% result.1$isnum)
# [1] FALSE
```

---

**EDIT**: Response to OPs comment.

Comparing the number of rows is not meaningful. The join will return rows corresponding to all matches. So if a given `idnum` is present twice in `dt` and three times  in `ids`, you will get 2 X 3 = 6 rows in the result. The important test is the one I did: are any of the ids in `result.1` also present in `result.2`? If so, then there's something wrong.

If you have duplicated `ids$idnum`, try:

```
result.1 <- dt[J(unique(ids$idnum))]    # inclusive set (records with common ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried implementing that, but my numbers don't add up (see the update of the question).